# Automating Google BigQuery query without local access to APIs

Tags: automation, google-bigquery

I'm trying to automatically run a bigquery query every week and save the data onto my computer.

Ideally this would be done through the APIs but due to issues with proxies and firewalls in work I cannot access the APIs on my computer.

Are there any other options available to me? I have tried looking into Google Compute Engine but I'm not quite sure if this will help me

It is necessary to get the data from BigQuery as well, standard GAP reporting through the WebUI will not suffice. And the query will result in ~ 2,000,000 rows of data each week

Comment: per your statement - you cannot access APIs from you work computer because of some issues with proxies, firewalls, etc. What it is that you have accees with to GBQ from your computer? BQ UI, bq command line, anything else? please clarify - this will help to answer second part of your requirement - " save the data onto my computer"

Comment: Apologies, should have clarified that. At the moment I am running the queries through the BQ ui and from there I save and export a table to cloud storage and download a CSV to my computer from there. This is process that I want to try automate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might know, BigQuery by itself doesn’t provide any scheduling mechanism.
You should use 3rd party solution or develop your own.
As an example, you can use App Engine Cron Service to automate BQ query execution and exporting result to GCS.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#cron
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart

To get your result from GCS to local computer you still need some sort of access to cloud and use respective tool (see link below)
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: Great. So if I understand correctly, I can write and run a script on the App Engine and schedule it with cron, then use gsutil to download the saved data from GCS?

Comment: Correct. This is definitelly an option for you

Comment: There is yet another option/solution that I can deliver as a part of BigQuery Mate - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh - If I see good votes/feedback on this comment, I can do it in next version of this extension. Please don’t ask yet for how this will work – but short story - it will allow to do what is asked in the question without any extra coding from user’s side and will be a part of regular GBQ UI.
Of course some limitations will be applied :o)

Comment: You could also use Google Apps Script to talk to BigQuery (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) with a Time based trigger to kick off the script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).